# Inserir coluna do excel em uma tabela no MySQL

Tags: mysql, microsoft-excel

Eu tenho uma tabela do mysql(possui 600 registros):
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A coluna **edr_id** é uma coluna que será extraída de uma célula do excel,entretando na ferramenta que estou utilizando (**MySQL for Excel**), não tem a opção de update apenas de adicionar e quando eu adiciono a célula é como se eu adicionasse mais registros.
Existe alguma ferramenta onde é possível fazer o update usando a célula do Excel?

Comment: Você pode importar esses dados do excel para uma nova tabela, depois faça o update (tabela do MySQL para MySQL).

Comment: Nossa a solução é mais simples do que eu pensava,teria como escrever uma resposta com um exemplo de como seria a query e eu aproveito para aceitar a resposta,ja que você me ajudou.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creio que não terá grandes diferenças do Sql para o [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html), pois o exemplo que criei fiz no Sql. Bom, no exemplo imagine que a TabelaA corresponde com a tabela que você já importou, a TabelaB será a nova tabela importada e que terá o valor da coluna edr_id a ser utilizada para atualizar o respectivo campo na TabelaA. Segue a instrução (Sql):

```
update
  TabelaA
set
  edr_id = TabelaB.edr_id
from
  TabelaA
    inner join
  TabelaB
     on TabelaA.dados_cidades_id = Tabelab.dados_cidade_id
```

Caso tenha algum critério não esqueça de utilizar a cláusula WHERE.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda a query que resolveu o problema caso alguém precise no MySQL foi:
update
  dados_cidades
inner join
  lalaa
     on dados_cidades.dados_cidades_id = lalaa.lalaa_id
set
  dados_cidades.edr_id = lalaa.edr_id